# Getting an "External Exception 0"

Tags: ios, firemonkey

I have been plagued with this error for several months.  Sometimes it occurs and sometimes it does not.

I have several TComboBoxes or TComboEdits in my application.

I am doing nothing more that populate the control with a SQLite query via an array of string values.

I have coded no change events.  Just touching the control brings up the iOS native control which has the list contents.  However, sometimes touching the control causes the "External Exception 0" error.  This is maddening.

Anyone else encounter this error?

Comment: I've encountered it. I don't have a solution. On IOS too. Sometimes it happens sometimes it doesn't. We load text into the TComboEdit with MyComboEdit.Items.AddStrings(). Usually happens on the first TComboEdit on the form (we have a lot of them).

Comment: Nice to know that I am not the only one experiencing this gremlin.  I think I have a work around, but I am not ready to report it because the "jury is still out" on this issue.  I will report back when I have concrete proof.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered `external exception 0 in android`. How I got the problem and what changes I did to get rid of it I will tell.

**I was invoking a third form from a second form (by lazy creation and showing)**. The third form displayed fine but *when I tried to access any control in the parent form through the second form's unit* (included in the implementation uses section of third form) like `uSecond.Form2.myControl` I got that exception (note: Form2 is the global var in uSecond).

How I solved the issue was I put the mainForm's unit besides the uSecond in the implementation uses of the third form and ensured that units of both form2, form3 were present in the mainForm's implementation uses section. Then I referenced in my third form - **the global var defined for the same second form but in the mainForm** (not in uSecond) like `uMain.FormTwo.myControl`

Note that **Form2** and **FormTwo** are two different identifiers.